# modification of hidden field using jquery working in development not in server rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in the view of a page in my rails application to calculate the price and submit an order using jquery. Here is the form first

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
<% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

      <div class="col-md-12">
       <div id="customs-form">
           <span class="badge">1</span>
          <%= f.label "Select your model location*" %>
          <%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :formatted_display, { prompt: true }, :required => true,  :class => 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">2</span>
          <%= f.label "Select Your model" %>
          <%= f.select :performer_id, grouped_options_for_select(Location.order(:name).map{ |group| [group.name, group.performers.map{ |performer| [performer.first_name, performer.id, {'data-whitelabel_amount'=>performer.white_label.w_markup, 'data-thumb' => performer.profile_thumb_url,'data-id'=>performer.white_label.id, 'data-admin' => performer.white_label.markup.price }] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true, class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">3</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT YOUR CATEGORY" %>
          <%= f.select :clip_category_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.clip_category_performers.map{ |c| [c.clip_category.name, c.clip_category.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true, class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">4</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT THE DURATION" %>
          <%= f.select :duration_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.duration_performers.map{ |c| [c.duration.time, c.duration.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }),{ prompt: true},  required: true, class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">5</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT THE QUALITY" %>
          <%= f.select :quality_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.quality_performers.map{ |c| [c.quality.name , c.quality.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true,  class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">6</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT DELIVERY TIME" %>

          <%= f.select :delivery_time_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.delivery_time_performers.map{ |c| [c.delivery_time.duration, c.delivery_time.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true,  class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>
        <span class="badge">7</span>

        <%= f.label "Write your description"%>

             <% if session[:from_site] %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :affiliate_id, :value=>@prev_website_id%>
     <%end %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 4, :cols => 60, maxlength: 999, :class => "order_desc order_form form-control" %>
        <span id="remainingC"><p class="help-block">Content limited to 999 characters, remaining: 999</p></span>
        <%= f.hidden_field :total, value: "", id: "order_total"%>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => current_user.email%>
        <% end %>
        <div class="actions" >
          <h4 class="alert1"><p class ="help-block">*Please buy credits before you order as customer</p></h4>
          <%= f.button :"ORDER NOW", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-marketing" %>
        </div>

    </div>
     <!-- <div class="actions" onclick="check()">-->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery that I used

```
 read = function(){ 

function calculate_perf_total()
{
  category_amount = parseFloat($('#order_clip_category_id :selected').data('amount')) || 0
  duration_amount = parseFloat($('#order_duration_id :selected').data('amount')) || 0
  quality_amount = parseFloat($('#order_quality_id :selected').data('amount')) || 0
  delivery_amount = parseFloat($('#order_delivery_time_id :selected').data('amount')) || 0
   perf_addition=(category_amount + duration_amount + quality_amount+delivery_amount)
   if(category_amount && duration_amount && delivery_amount && quality_amount)
   {
    console.log("hello you are here")
   white_label_amount = parseFloat($('#order_performer_id :selected').data('whitelabel_amount')) || 1
    if(white_label_amount==1)
    {
      white_label_amount=parseFloat($('#white_label_id_price').data('amount')) || 1
    }
    affiliate_amount=parseFloat($('#affiliate_id_price').data('amount')) || 1
    admin_amount = parseFloat($('#super_admin_price').data('amount')) || 1
    if(admin_amount==1)
    {
      admin_amount=parseFloat($('#order_performer_id :selected').data('admin'))
    }
    admin_cut=perf_addition*admin_amount
    console.log("admin_amount")
    console.log(admin_amount)
    console.log("admin_cut")
    console.log(admin_cut)

    if(parseFloat($('#order_performer_id :selected').data('id')) ==1 || parseFloat($('#white_label_id').data('amount'))==1) 
    {
      other_cut=0
    }
    else
    {
      other_cut=perf_addition*white_label_amount
    }
    console.log("other_cut")
    console.log(other_cut)
    if(affiliate_amount!=1)
    {
      other_cut_1=perf_addition*affiliate_amount
      // alert(other_cut_1)
    }
    else
    {
      other_cut_1=0
    }
    console.log("other_cut_1")
    console.log(other_cut_1)
    // alert(window.my_config.perf_addition+other_cut+admin_cut)
    total_amount=perf_addition+other_cut+admin_cut+other_cut_1
    // alert(total_amount)
      //alert(total_amount)
      $('#total_amount').html(Math.ceil(total_amount));
      // alert($('#order_total'))
      $('#order_total').val(Math.ceil(total_amount));  
   }
   else
   {
      // alert(window.my_config.perf_addition);
      //alert(total_amount)
      $('#total_amount').html(Math.ceil(perf_addition))  
    }
}



    $('#order_clip_category_id').change(function()
    {
      //alert("alert1");
        calculate_perf_total()  
    });

    $('#order_duration_id').change(function()
    {
      //alert("alert2");
    calculate_perf_total()  
    });

    $('#order_quality_id').change(function()
    {
      // alert("alert3");
    calculate_perf_total()  
    });

    $('#order_delivery_time_id').change(function()
    {
      // alert("alert4");
    calculate_perf_total()
    // calculate_total()  
    });  
}
$(document).ready(read);
$(document).on('page:load', read);
```

The calculation and the value of the hidden field `order_total` is getting set in the local but it is not happening in the production. It is killing my project. Any ideas?

Comment: check the publuc/ folder and see if it's not cached.

Comment: Sounds like an asset problem, check that the JS exist in your rendered document in production.